# Why does $h = v\cos\alpha$ never enter into the Mean Value Theorem Proof?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, visualization

[*Calculus: The Language Of Change*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0763729477) (2005)
by David W. Cohen, James M. Henle. [pp. 827-829](https://books.google.com/books?id=QNfZls4urMoC&pg=PA827&lpg=PA827&dq=mean+value+theorem+proof+tilt&source=bl&ots=WjLggTfZBQ&sig=5hcMBO1xjIv5xt7Fejr9C7LQkoM&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=vz0PU8KbOundigeLv4DwDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=true). The original colored in just blue. I annotated and added more colors.

Pls see below. Why do $\color{pink}{h}, \color{forestgreen}{v}, \alpha$ never enter or show up in the Mean Value Theorem Proof below? It feels wrong that $\color{pink}{h} = \color{forestgreen}{v}\cos\alpha$ (Exercise 4 on p. 829)  transforms   $\color{pink}{h}$ in Fig. 2 to $\color{forestgreen}{v}$ in Fig. 3, but the Mean Value Theorem Proof never features $\color{pink}{h}, \color{forestgreen}{v}, \alpha$.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the mean value theorem proof or the excercise number 4 on your picture?

Comment: @SebastianCor MVT proof.

Comment: The mvt proof is general, as in, it applies to all continuous functions satisfying the hypotheses of it. 

$h,v,\alpha$ are values of a particular case which is seen in the picture.

Comment: The authors attempt to draw a geometric connection between a "tilted Rolle's theorem" and the mean value theorem, which I feel is not relevant. As you noted, the "tilted Rolle's theorem" does not appear at all in the proof; rather, the proof applies Rolle's theorem on the function $s(t)$ which is the difference between $f$ and the chord (not a "rotation" or "tilt" of $f$). I would not dwell on this too much.

Comment: The usage of $h, v, \alpha$ is the explanation given in your question is to demonstrate that the proof can be carried out by considering the vertical distance (parallel to $y$ axis) between point on curve and point on chord instead of the perpendicular distance of the point on curve from the chord. Hence it does not need to enter in the proof. On the other hand if the proof is carried out using perpendicular distance then one can consider the $r(t) =s(t) \cos \alpha$ and proceed further.

Comment: If this is an example of proofs given in your book, then consider yourself lucky as the author here makes a serious attempt to help readers understand calculus. Where calculus is concerned most books at intro level are simply trash.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks. "Hence it does not need to enter in the proof." Sorry...I still don't grasp why $h, v, \alpha$ don't need to enter proof?

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, comparing the picture from the exercise with the picture from the proof of the theorem at p. 828, $h$, $v$, and $\alpha$ from the exercise, in the proof of the theorem are called the perpendicular distance (which is the distance between a current point $f(t)$ on a graph and the chord), the vertical distance (between the current point and its horizontal projection into the chord), and the angle of the elevation of the chord, respectively. In the proof we want to maximize the perpendicular distance $h$. But $h$ is equal to the product of the vertical distance $v$ by a $\cos \alpha$. Since the chord endpoints $(c,f(c))$ and $(d,f(d))$ are fixed, $\cos \alpha=\tfrac{d-c}{\sqrt{(d-c)^2+(f(d)-f(c))^2}}$ is a *constant*. So we are maximizing the vertical distance $v$. Moreover, later the vertical distance is denoted by $s(t)=f(t)-q(t)$.